# Import data from Excel into existing dataTable when DB properties not match first column in excel ASp.NET / core

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, excel, asp.net-core

Picture for example of excel file first column (is not Claim Number, its column K):

[image]

> My project suppose to import data from Excel and Xml files, XML-part is done,
>   but the problem with Excel is that first column (meaning properties) in the files that I'll import doesn't match the existing data Table i have
>
> A part of properties i have:

```
 public string ClaimNo { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string Uwyear { get; set; }
    public string AgreementNo { get; set; }
    public string BusinessType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PeriodStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PeriodEnd { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNo { get; set; }
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfLoss { get; set; }
    public string ClaimantName { get; set; }
    public string ClaimedInsured { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }
```

> I'm working on asp.net core, already wrote a code for exporting data from DB into a excel file but it has'nt so many properties like those excel files i'm trying to import data from and the first column was harcoded.
>   I used EEPlus.Core for it.
>
> I already wrote the function that import the xls file

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> XLSPage(IFormFile xlsFile)
    {
        var uploadsRoot = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsRoot, xlsFile.FileName).ToString();
        if (xlsFile.ContentType.Equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await xlsFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                    var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));

                    ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

                   //The code that i need to read data from Excel  
                //and fill in it into my dataTable 



                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var str = e.Message;
                TempData["XlsConvertErrorMsg"] = "Converting fail, check if your data is correct";
                return View();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            TempData["XlsUploadErrorMsg"] = "Uploadin fail, check if your file is xls";
            return View();
        }
        TempData["XlsUploadConvertSuccesMsg"] = "Uploading, converting of Excel succeeded!";
        return View(nameof(ImportExportXlsController.Index)); ;
    }
```

Comment: So the "claim no" is missing what do you want us to do about that? In the code to populate datatable skip the column if it is missing.

Comment: When i Will transfer data and for example want the value of column claim number from excel file into ClaimNo in DataTable, is there any attribute or nuget package that allow me to relate them such as in xml-deserializing there we have [XmlElement("****")]

Comment: The column is missing, there isn't data for Claim Number unless its hiding in a column with 0 width?

Comment: Yes there is data, and I'm seen it , it is on the column 'K'

Comment: This is not about `ClosedXML`. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the Claim Number is on column K in the XLSX files and on column 1 in the XML files.

Here is the code to read data from Excel and fill a dataTable and then change the column indexes:

```
//Get the values in the sheet
object[,] valueArray = workSheet.Cells.GetValue<object[,]>();

int maxRows = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; 
int maxColumns = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Column Headers
for (int col = 0; col < maxColumns; col++)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(valueArray[0,col]);
}
//Import Excel Data ot DataTable
for (int row = 1; row < maxRows; row++)
{
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  for (int col = 0; col < maxColumns; col++)
  {
      dr[col] = valueArray[row,col].ToString();
  }
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
//Set the Column order
dt.Columns["Claim Number"].SetOrdinal(0);
```

Edit 1:

If Datatable isn't available yet have a list of records/claims and make a map of the column indexes based on header names.

```
public class Claim
{
public string ClaimNo { get; set; } 
public string ClientName { get; set; } 
public string Uwyear { get; set; } 
public string AgreementNo { get; set; } 
public string BusinessType { get; set; } 
public DateTime? PeriodStart { get; set; } public DateTime? PeriodEnd { get; set; } 
public string PolicyNo { get; set; } 
public string PolicyName { get; set; } 
public DateTime? DateOfLoss { get; set; } public string ClaimantName { get; set; } 
public string ClaimedInsured { get; set; } 
public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }

}
```

....

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

for (int row = 1; row < maxRows; row++)
{
      var c = new Claim();
      c.ClaimNo= valueArray[row,MapCol("ClaimNo")].ToString();
      c.ClientName= valueArray[row,MapCol("ClientName")].ToString();
       ...         
}
claims.Add(c);
```

Edit 2:

Use a Dictionary to hold the column number and name. Then when you read the Excel Header row you can populate the Dictionary at run-time without hardcoding.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionaryColIndexs = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int col = 0; col < maxColumns; col++)
{
   dictionaryColIndexs.Add(valueArray[0,col],col);
}
```

...

```
private int MapCol(string colName)
{
   if (dictionaryColIndexs.ContainsKey(colName))
   {
      int index= dictionaryColIndexs[colName];
      return index;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, seems to work. Thx a lot! Will test it when I wake up.

Comment: DataTable is not compatible yet on ASP.NET Core :(, but thx a lot for your efforts :)

Comment: Thx for quick answer, i'm updating my VS, will test it as soon it launchs

Comment: What's MapCol ? I don't get it recognized, i try it with setting ColumnAttribute on parameters ex.:                                                                        [Column("ClientName")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        [Column("UWYear")]
        public string Uwyear { get; set; }                                                              but no result

Comment: Now i Understand it ,                                                                                    private int MapCol(string value)
        {

            if (value == "ClientName")
                return 1;
            if (value == "Uwyear")
                return 2;
            if (value == "AgreementNo")
                return 3;
            if (value == "AgreementName")
                return 4;

Comment: Glad you could work it out yourself, see my second edit

Comment: thx a lot, it work now, having problem with other types (decimal, datetime, int) casting but im so thankfull for all your help